# SQL Query - duplicate values on columns

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Using myphphadmin

The issue I'm having is that there are duplicate values on 2 of my columns when there should be values e.g the productID should be different. I've been trying find a solution to fix it but I can't - can anyone help?

This is the SQL from the query if it helps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Staff.staffID, Staff.sFirst_Name, 
    Product.productID, Product.productName, 
    count(*)
FROM
    Staff
INNER JOIN 
    Product ON Product.productID = Product.productID
GROUP BY 
    Staff.sFirst_Name, Product.productName
HAVING
    count(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    Staff.sFirst_Name ASC
```

Output of that query:

```
staffID sFirst_Name     productID   productName     count(*)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2001    Jason            7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2002    Lisa             7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2006    Luke             7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2007    Oscar            7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2003    Ryan             7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2004    Stephenie        7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
2005    Tasnima          7001   ClarinsMen Super Moisture Balm 50ml     26
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, I don't see any duplicates in the output.  You really should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: join condition `Product.productID = Product.productID` probably makes no sense (unless you want to eliminate NULL values)

Answer (score 0):

After the INNER JOIN you should match a primary key with a foreign key, you're matching two times Product.productID so everytime it will show every Staff entry with the same product